# Visual Studio 2008 (C#) with SQL Compact Edition database error: 26

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, database-connection

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

I've created a SQL compact database, included it in my application, and can connect to the database fine from other database editors, but within my application im trying

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnection))
{
    con.Open();
}
```

the connection string is

> Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf

I'm stumped, any insight?

Comment: Why not put the exact path instead of using |DataDirectory| to see if its an issue with that. At least with the exact path you could narrow the issue down a little more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of connection object. SqlConnection is for the grown up SQL server, not for SQL Server Compact.

[connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce) has the connection strings you need. For the connection object itself I believe you need the [SqlCeconnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28VS.80%29.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

use `SqlCeConnection` instead of `SqlConnection`, include the namespace `System.Data.SqlServerCe` instead of `System.Data.SqlServer`.

[See this article for an example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6bdd883a-e1dc-4c6e-8b9c-7d4a98569db7/)