# using sql server with vs 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Am facing a problem with using SQL server 2012 along with VS 2012 ,, when I try to make new database it gives me this ERROR : 

 
“A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)”

I've tried to install the SQL Server Express 2012 again but still the same problem. 

 
any suggestions ? 

 
thanks in advance .

Comment: Some problem with you connection string...

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911286/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne)

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably you are something missing in ConnectionString, might be server name
open sql server and check server name.

working connectionString: